# Joomla Wysiwyg & jquery post problem

Tags: jquery, post, joomla, wysiwyg

I'm using this joomla method to display a wysiwyg editor inside my custom app.

```
// this initiates the wysiwig

<?php $editor =& JFactory::getEditor(); ?> 

// this displays a text area with the wysiwyg 

<?php echo $editor->display("desc",$desc,'100%','300','20','20','0'); ?>
```

I now want to POST the content of that text-area off, through my inline jquery script

```
// SAVE THE FORM  DATA   

$('#SAVELISTING').click(function(){

if (confirm("Click OK to save the data"))
{

var txt = $.ajax({
url: 'update.php',
async: true, 
type:'POST',

data:({  

id:$('input#id').val(),
listTitle:$('input#listTitle').val(),
introdesc:$('textarea#introdesc').val(),  
fulldesc:$(JRequest::getVar('textarea#desc')).val() 

})   

}).success; 
$('.alert').show('slow');
}
});
```

Which in turn sends it to my update.php script.

```
$desc = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['fulldesc']); 

DO THE INSERT
```

The firebug response i get is ***JRequest is not defined***

**Update**

---

And this is the normal method joomla uses for posting the data, can anyone work out maybe from that how i would pst the data inside my jquery code above?

```
/*The store-procedure in your model might then look like this*/
[...] 
function store()
{
  $row =& $this->getTable();
  $data = JRequest::get( 'post');
  /* Get proper HTML-code for your HTML-encoded field now by using JREQUEST_ALLOWHTML*/
  $data['yourfieldname']=JRequest::getVar( 'yourfieldname', '', 'post', 'string', JREQUEST_ALLOWHTML );
  /* now proceed as suggested */

  $row->bind($data);
  [...] 
  $row->check();
  [...] 
  $row->store();
  [...] 
}
[...]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
fulldesc:$(<?php echo JRequest::getVar('textarea#desc')%>).val()
```

After looking at your update I'm not even sure you need the JRequest call.  Try:

```
fulldesc:$('textarea#desc').val()
```

Comment: Andrew thanks for the tip but unfortunately im still stuck. I think its something to do with the getVAr and the value insid ethe barckets but im not quite sure how to tackle it. Still googling..

Comment: The problem is that you're calling a Joomla function from your javascript.  I think you need to call the function from your PHP code on the server and embed the result in the javascript returned to the client.  Is this right?

Comment: Yes you are right, its just trying to work that bit out. I havent learned a framework yet so i use simple methods of php , mysql, and a bit of jquery to do the job. It works and i understand it until i hit an issue like this.

Comment: Hi Andrew, yes i did try that too but it didnt work. I have gone back to using CLEDITOR inside my custom component which posts data via jquery just fine. I just hate trying to fix the strange symbols that appear inside the textaraea after posting it. you know the silly A with the curly hiphen above it?